# Aggregation within date periods

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a list of categories and another table of entries that has a relation to which category it belongs too. I'm trying to aggregate these which works fine, but when I add a date parameter, any category that has no entry within that period doesn't show up, I'd like it to show up as 0.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.label, COUNT(e.user_id) AS TOTAL
FROM category c, entry e
WHERE c.id NOT IN (19,20)
WHERE e.category_id(+) = c.id
AND e.date_added > (SYSDATE - 14) -- Problem
GROUP BY(c.label)
```

I understand why it doesn't show up, just not sure the way around it?

**Update**

Category table 
- id 
- label
...

Entry table
- id
- category_id
- e.user_id
...

It's all the entries over a given period group into which category they belong to. I want to show all my categories though, even if there were no entries during that given period. I thought an outer join would solve this.

Comment: Show us the input data you have and the expected output, I don't really understand where you want to get data if it doesn't store in your database.

Comment: @zaratustra updated my Q. The data is in the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, learn proper `join` syntax.  And, you don't need `select distinct` when you are using `group by`.  Your query would then look like:

```
SELECT c.label, COUNT(e.id) AS TOTAL
FROM category c LEFT JOIN
     entry e
     ON e.category_id = c.id
WHERE c.id NOT IN (19, 20) AND e.date_added > (SYSDATE - 14)
GROUP BY c.label;
```

Then, if you want to keep all categories, move the condition on the second table (`e`) into the `on` clause:

```
SELECT c.label, COUNT(e.id) AS TOTAL
FROM category c LEFT JOIN
     entry e
     ON e.category_id = c.id AND
        e.date_added > (SYSDATE - 14)
WHERE c.id NOT IN (19, 20)
GROUP BY c.label;
```

This is one example of why the explicit `join` syntax is better.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I have always used joins in your method. But I recently got involved with oracle and people used that syntax, so I assumed that was the way to do it. I will go back to my original way and thanks for pointing out to move the second condition ~ Jonny

Comment: @Jonnny . . . Oracle has supported proper `join` syntax for over a decade (since version 8i).  I appreciate that there are Oracle developers who still use commas in the `from` clause.  But trying to understand the outer join syntax is . . . not worth the effort.